# Using Regex (or something similar) to replace commas with words (porting Java project to Objective C)

Tags: java, objective-c, regex, porting

I am porting my game from Java to Objective C and I have a large amount of level data.  I am hoping there is a simple way to change it over using some sort of replacement via regex.

The java format looks like this -

```
level1.addWave(240, 0, 120, 1, Constants.DOWN_STRAIGHT, .03f, 0.15f, 
Constants.WANDER_RIGHT, Constants.TOP_SIDE, 250, 390, Sheep.WHITE, 2);
```

and the Objective C version should look like this -

```
[level1 addWave_offset:0 waveTimer:0 nextSheepCD:0 numberOfWaves:1 startingDirection:DOWN_STRAIGHT wanderRate:0.03 wanderLean:0.15 
wanderDirection:WANDER_NONE side:TOP_SIDE minPixel:200 maxPixel:200 type:WHITE amount:1];
```

Is there a way to do this replacement via regex?

Comment: "If you have a procedure with ten parameters, you probably missed some." -- Alan J. Perlis

Comment: If I changed this question to be abstract and simply about regex would that inspire you to give a real answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done similar things many times and my approach was following, i.e pseudo code:
- Iterate over all files in all directories
- Open file and read each line
- If your line starts with `level` then do further processing
- Further processing: Split the line with following tokens `(`, `Constants.`,  and `,`. Trim the results to remove white spaces.  Store each result in to associated temp variable (e.g. store `level1` into `tmp_level_id`)
- Use store results to generate Objective-C code

While this may not be as beautiful as some funky regex it will be easier to implement and fix if necessary.

Kind regards,
Bo